# R Paste " " around string

Tags: r, paste, quote

I create a function and need to paste " " around the string, the final desired code is `'table_df'` in the following code

```
if (exists('table_df') && is.data.frame(get('table_df'))&nrow(table_df)>0) {
tracking_sheet$var1[tracking_sheet$var2=="table_name"]<-'Completed'
} else {tracking_sheet$var1[tracking_sheet$var2=="table_name"]<-'Check'}
```

this is my function, but it doesnt work, mainly because of the quotes around the string part. `paste('", table_df, "',sep="")`, so my question is how to use paste or other function to achieve the final result `'table_df'`

```
check<-defmacro(tracking_sheet,table_df,table_name,
expr={if (exists(paste('", table_df, "',sep="")) && is.data.frame(get(paste('", table_df, "',sep="")))&nrow(table_df)>0) {
  tracking_sheet$var1[tracking_sheet$var2==table_name]<-'Completed'
} else {tracking_sheet$var1[tracking_sheet$var2==table_name]<-'Check'}
              })
check(tracking_sheet,app_df_pivot,"T_Applications")
```

the code above is trying to create a summary sheet to report which dataframe is existed in the environment and if the df contains data. I am welcome to all advice and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to use

```
paste('"', table_df, '"',sep="")
```

Without the closing single-quotes,

```
paste('", table_df, "',sep="")
```

evaluates to ", table_df, "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste a quote, you have to escape it with "\"

```
paste0("\'", "example", "\'")
```